AWS AMplify: (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied on S3 bucket
I use a lambda function that calls the s3 bucket and renames the filename of a photo that is stored in the S3 bucket. I get access denied although the policy is set as following:

    {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Sid": "PutAndDelS3",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }

what am I doing wrong?

When your Lambda function tries to rename a file in your S3 bucket, you need to ensure that the Lambda's execution role has the necessary permissions not only for s3:PutObject and s3:DeleteObject but also for s3:GetObject. This is because renaming in S3 involves copying (requiring GetObject and PutObject) and then deleting the original file. You can update your IAM policy to:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
            "Sid": "GetPutAndDelS3",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

Make sure this policy is attached to the Lambda function's execution role, and confirm that there are no conflicting bucket policies that might override this permission.

lambda function has the correct role.
How can I check the bucket's policies?

Did you just add ** s3:GetObject** and have you tried afterwards and still get an error? As your original message didn’t have this action. As for the bucket policy, you can check that on S3 > yourbucket > Permissions > Bucket policy. Also, when you say you get access denied, where do you get this error? From your lambda function?

yes, when I test the lambda function I get this error. I modified my policy according to your changes and I still get the error

i removed the "block all public access" on my S3 bucket and I managed to use DeleteObject from my lambda function. But CopyObject still has no access. What do I need to modify to give acces for this? My desired result is to rename a photo from the s3 bucket
